# Google Closure Linter not working in Sublime Text 2 for Windows

Tags: javascript, python, google-closure-compiler, sublimetext2

Has anyone gotten the Google Closure Linter (**gjslint**) to work with Sublime Text 2 for Windows?

When I run it I get the following (via Tools menu or CTRL+SHIFT+J):

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
>
> closure linter: ignored 0 errors.

My steps were as follows:

- Installed [Python 2.7](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.3/)
- Installed [Setup Tools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/) for [Easy Install](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall#installing-easy-install)
- Installed the [Closure Linter](https://developers.google.com/closure/utilities/docs/linter_howto)
- Installed the [ST2 Plugin](https://github.com/fbzhong/sublime-closure-linter)

Out of the box, none of the features worked.  However if I hard-code the path in the Default Settings I can get the **fixjsstyle** plugin to work:

```
{
    // Path to the gjslint.
    "gjslint_path": "/python27/scripts/gjslint",

    // Path to the fixjsstyle.
    "fixjsstyle_path": "/python27/scripts/fixjsstyle"
}
```

Can confirm they both exist:

```
C:\>dir c:\python27\scripts
 Volume in drive C is OSDisk
 Volume Serial Number is 36E3-7433

 Directory of c:\python27\scripts

...
06/29/2012  09:48 AM               304 fixjsstyle-script.py
06/29/2012  09:48 AM             7,168 fixjsstyle.exe
06/29/2012  09:48 AM               525 fixjsstyle.exe.manifest
06/29/2012  09:48 AM               298 gjslint-script.py
06/29/2012  09:48 AM             7,168 gjslint.exe
06/29/2012  09:48 AM               522 gjslint.exe.manifest
              17 File(s)         34,580 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  186,377,805,824 bytes free
```

It certainly sounds like a reference problem, I even tried copying the executables to the plugin directory, that didn't work either.

*Edit*: I should add that I did turn on the `debug: true` flag and nothing came up.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue on Windows 7.
The only way i found to fix it was to remove the double quotes around the `gjslint` call

**line 34** of `gjslint.py` inside the `sublime` package

original (not working):

```
cmd = '"' + s.get('gjslint_path', 'jslint') + '" ' + s.get('gjslint_flags', '') + ' "' + file_path + '"'
```

working :

```
cmd = '' + s.get('gjslint_path', 'jslint') + ' ' + s.get('gjslint_flags', '') + ' "' + file_path + '"'
```

Please make sure your `gjslint` path has not any spaces to make this work as it's the case for you.

If somebody has another solution, please share.

Comment: Worked for me. Windows 7 too.

Comment: Thanks! Typed that in and bingo. Not a python expert so super thanks!